# Background API calls are causing server errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux

I have an application where I need to get status and messages every 5 seconds. These calls are being made on my main page AsyncApp.js thats hold the frame (navigation bars etc...) of the app. The issue is when a user goes to a new page that has many api calls of its own to get the data it needs to render the page in component did mount, the server crashes with the error "can't set headers after they are sent". I know this really doesn't have to do with headers, but instead with making to many api calls all at once.

I have tried using async and await which works okay, until a page with a lot of api calls of its own is rendered at the same time as one of the status calls goes out. I tried using Promises because I was thinking promises will not hold the program up like async and await but instead take its time if some other activity is going on. I don't know whether promises are the right way to go and I am simply using them wrong or maybe I need to set up child processes. Which I have never done before so I am completely unfamiliar with. I am very new to nodejs and web development.

notifications(){

```
const { dispatch } = this.props

this.newNotifications = setInterval( async () => {

  let data = { since_last_checked : this.state.sinceLastCheck }
  let res1 = await fetch('/api/getNotifications', {
    method:'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'accept': 'application/json'
    },
    body:JSON.stringify(data)
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
  .done()

  console.log("NOTIFICATIONS", res1)

  //if(res1 === undefined || res1.data === undefined || res1.data === null){
    //this.setState({redirect: true})
  //}

  //if(res1 !== undefined && res1.data !== null && res1.data.messages) dispatch(updateMessages(res1.data.messages.slice(9)))

  let res2 = await fetch('/api/getStatus')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
  .done()

  console.log("STATUS", res2)

  //if(res2 === undefined || res2.data === undefined || res2.data === null || res2.data.is_active === 'N' || res2.data.status === 'closed'){
    //this.setState({redirect: true})
  //}

}, 5000)
```

//My requests are being fulfilled by a websocket

```
function getData(url, pugCommand){

  app.get(url, (req, res) => {

    console.log("URL", url)

    let parsedUrl = urltest.parse(url);
    let parsedQs = querystring.parse(parsedUrl.query);

    stompClient = new StompJs.Client({
        connectHeaders: { login: "statemanager", passcode: "Ion_1551" },
        brokerURL: brokerURL,
        reconnectDelay: 200,
        //debug: (str) =>  { console.log("DEBUG", str) },
        onConnect: () => { sendCommandToPUG(pugCommand[0], pugCommand[1],  pugCommand[2], stompClient, req.session.userID, req.session.pugSessionID); },
        onUnhandledMessage: (messageReply) => {

            reply = JSON.parse(messageReply.body);
            if(reply.status.errorOccured)
                console.log("PUG-SERVER RETURNED ERROR: " + reply.status.errorText);

            replyData = reply.data; //here is where you will find all the data that matches your query (eg: fields/rows)
            return res.json(reply);
            //stompClient.disconnect();
        },
    });
    stompClient.activate();

  });
}
```

//i am making the call here

```
getData('/api/getStatus', ["GET_SESSION_STATUS", "SESSIONS",  { '' : ''}]);
```

Cant set headers after they are sent is the usual error but I believe I am blocking the event loop which is causing this error.

Comment: This error is usually thrown when you respond to a request multiple times in you route handler in express app. Can you show the express route that causes this error? You likely call `res.json(..)` or `res.send(...)` more than once. Also instead of polling your server every 5 seconds it might be much better idea to use websockets and send the data when a status changes or new notification appears so you only send data between client and server when needed.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the error you are getting Is because you are sending multiple responses  from the API, not because you are sending multiple requests to your API.

Check your node script and make sure you're making a single res.send(...) For each possible path on your script

Answer (score 0):

`.then(res => res.json()),` these same line you are using it two times in your code, you cant send res twice, you can use the first response to calculate the second one.

You should not use await and .then block together, if you use await then the response will returned to variable assigned.

You can use it like these -

```
const promisify_fetch = promisify(fetch);
  let res1 = await promisify_fetch('/api/getNotifications', {
    method:'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'accept': 'application/json'
    },
    body:JSON.stringify(data)
  });
  if (!res) throw "error occurred"
  res1 = res1.json();
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand I am using res.json() on two different api calls, each ones needs to be transformed in json seperately in order to see the content of the call

Comment: you can push both the results into an array and then send the result into the response.